# How to create a newline without breaking the token?

Tags: c++, file-io, token, newline, strtok

So I am trying to write to a file I/O in C++ where the user wants to translate a different language, an example would be morse code to english. I using the function morseToEnglish() and passing it in as a token for my output file. The issue I am having with this is that I am getting the correct output, but I am missing a newline somewhere.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        char morsing[256]; //reading line by line
        if (inputfile.is_open())
        { 
            while (inputfile.getline(morsing, 256)) // reading character by character
            {                                    
                token = strtok(morsing, "|"); //break each word into token
                cout << "Read the input file: " << "morsingMC.mc" << endl;
                while (token != NULL)
                {
                    **outputfile << morseToEnglish(morsing); **
                    token = strtok(NULL, "|");

                } 
            } 
        }
```

If I am doing

```
outputfile << morseToEnglish(morsing);
```

this will be the output:

```
123 456 789123 456 789123 456 789123 456 789123 456 789
```

instead of:

```
123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789
```

I have also tried using the endl and "\n" with my outputfile  but this will output each word into token instead. This is a minor change but how can I modify my newline so that my output will go to a newline without breaking the token?

Edit: morseToEnglish() is a function that converts morse code into English which is in the header file and inputfile/outputfile are ifstream/ofstream respectively

Comment: What is the content of `inputfile` and what is the implementation of `morseToEnglish()`?

Comment: I suggest to use https://godbolt.org/ to create a self contained [mre] so your question will get answered sooner.

Comment: the inputfile is an ifstream and morseToEnglish() is a function that converts morse code into english

Comment: Then how does anyone help without knowing the implementation of `morseToEnglish()` if your question is "why `morseToEnglish()`  does not output newline?". Your question is unclear to me unless we have all the details. Your snippet doesn't include newline so I presume it's inserted in ``morseToEnglish()`

Comment: morseToEnglish is in the header file which was already implemented

Comment: the function itself was able to translate into the output file correctly, but if i used a newline this would break the token that i have

Comment: I don't have crystal ball to see your implementation of `morseToEnglish(morsing)`. If the question is "what's wrong with `outputfile << morseToEnglish(morsing)`", the implementation must be provided.

Comment: Is `morseToEnglish()` a third party library? Let me rephrase my intent. How do you answer a question "what's wrong with `outstream << myfunc(foo)` " without knowing how `myfunc()` implemented?

Comment: In the code snippet, `token` doesn't matter because it's not output to the file (at least not in the snippet). Your function always takes `morsing` which is a `char` array instead of `token`.

Comment: My crystal ball told me that your bug would be resolved by `morseToEnglish(morsing)` --> `morseToEnglish(token)`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's start with a really simple bit of advice: when you're writing C++, forget that you ever even heard of `strtok`. Just don't use it--ever.

While you're at it, it's probably just as well to forget about the existence of `std::istream::getline` as well. If you want to read a line of data, your first choice should usually be `std::getline` instead. That works with an `std::string`--which should usually be your first choice for how to store/represent/manipulate strings.

Yes, there are exceptions to all of that, but they're reasonable starting points until/unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise.

Getting to the question, I surmise you have some input like:

```
<token>|<token>|<token>|<token>\n
```

So, for example, if a line of input contained the classic "SOS", it would be something like:

```
...|---|...
```

Seem at least sort of close to reality so far?

I'm also guessing that what you're hoping to achieve is read in a line, translate each token on that line into English, print out the tokens, print a new-line, and then proceed to the next, and repeat until the end of the file.

Assuming that's the case, I'd write the code something like this:

```cpp
std::string line;

while (std::getline(inputfile, line)) {
    process(line);
}
```

Then `process` will process one line of input, something like this:

```cpp
void process(std::string const &line) {
    std::istringstream buffer(line);

    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(buffer, token, '|')) {
        outputfile << morsetoenglish(token);
    }
    outputfile << '\n';
}
```

That is guessing about what you want, but if I'm reading things right, it seems to fit at least reasonably closely.